# Pylons Paste running with no output

Tags: python, pylons, paste

I've hit a snag while running through the hello world pylons example. I see the following in terminal after calling `paster serve development.ini` with the vanilla development.ini file.

```
Starting server in PID 14457.
serving on http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

However, when I navigate to 127.0.0.1:5000 in the browser I see Oops! Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:5000

What logs, if any, would help one understand what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using chrome, you might be experiencing this bug:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42058